# Find and replace '/ /' with ' /' using Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, find

I have a string:

```
var str = "Home / /thumbnail / /Test /Test1 /";
```

So, Here i want to replace  '/ /' with '/'. ie it should be

```
"Home /thumbnail /Test /Test1 /"
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gives me the desired result:

```
var str = "Home / /thumbnail / /Test /Test1 /";

str = str.split("/ /").join(" /");
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use CSS pseudo element rather than coding in the slash? 
    
     #breadcrumb > a:after{ content:'/'; }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
breadcrumb.replace('//','/');
```